# "A cerca de", "Acerca de", ou "Há cerca de"?

Tags: expressões

Sempre existe uma dúvida na hora de dizer "a respeito de", "sobre algo", utilizando a palavra "cerca" ou "acerca".

Qual a diferença entre as expressões "A cerca de", "Acerca de",  ou "Há cerca de"?

Answer (score 13):

`acerca de` distingue-se das outras duas expressões, é uma [locução prepositiva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locu%C3%A7%C3%A3o_prepositiva)  equivalente a "sobre", "a respeito de":

> Falávamos **acerca de** gramática.

que pode ser:

> Falávamos **sobre** gramática.

ou ainda:

> Falávamos **a respeito de** gramática.

Já as expressões `a cerca de` e `há cerca de` divergem no seu sentido devido à presença do `a` ou `há`.

Podemos entender melhor se partirmos as expressões em porções:

- `cerca de` é uma locução prepositiva que significa "aproximadamente" ou "perto de".
- `há`, vem do verbo haver, no sentido de existir, que pode ser substituído por existe(m), mais utilizado para indicar a "existência de algo".
- `a` é uma [preposição](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_(preposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) utilizada com `cerca de` para nos dar uma distância de espaço e tempo.

Sabendo isto, temos como exemplos:

`há cerca de`

> Na Stack Exchange **há** cerca de 1 bilião de perguntas com resposta aceite.

que pode ser:

> Na Stack Exchange **existem** cerca de 1 bilião de perguntas com resposta.

`a cerca de`

> A pedra passou a **cerca de** 2cm da minha cabeça.

que pode ser:

> A pedra passou a **aproximadamente** 2cm da minha cabeça.

Answer (score 8):

Vou falar **acerca de**sse assunto: **a cerca de** arame farpado arrebentou **há cerca de** dois dias, e ninguém consertou ainda.

```
[1]: Sobre
[2]: Uma cerca
[3]: Temporalidade (passado)
```

Comment: Eu não tenho certeza sobre o "há cerca de dois dias", pensando bem é um tanto estranho. Me parece que deveria ser "acerca de dois dias". Mas, novamente, não tenho certeza.

Comment: @VictorStafusa É "há cerca de dois dias" mesmo, tenho certeza. "Acerca" seria "sobre".

Comment: há cerca de = faz tanto tempo = passado

Comment: @AndréLyra Incluí a informação de que o [3] se refere ao passado

Comment: E há cerca de duzentas cabeças de gado na pastagem que agora estão em em risco de  se tresmalharem.